# Optimal Strategy

Tags: probability, statistics

Oil retails for $3 a gallon. due to fluctuations, the price in a month is estimated to be 2.5 with probability of 45% and 3.5 with probability of 55%. Suppose you are an investor with 20000 to invest. You are trying to decide how much oil to buy today to re-sell in a month.

What is the optimal investment strategy?

What is the expected profit of your strategy?

So for this question I know we should compute 0.45*2.5+3.5*0.55 which is 3.05, but I don't know how to continue with this path. Not quiet getting the optimal investment strategy concept.

Comment: We use dollar signs to set off MathJax.  If you want them in text, you need to escape them with backslashes.  Otherwise, you can just delete them because the unit of currency is not important.  What investment alternatives do you have?  Just to buy oil now, or are there options available?  How do you define an optimal strategy?  Just by expected value?

Comment: Yes, the only option is to buy oil now, and I need to decide how much oil to buy. In defining optimal strategy, I think it is to find the most profitable way to invest in a certain amount of gallon of oil.

Answer (score 1):

You have computed the expected value of a gallon is rising, so you should buy it.  Use all the money you have to buy oil.  You can compute the expected return by multiplying the number of gallons you can buy by the expected price and subtracting your investment.

Comment: So in this case, I use 20000 to buy oil, I can buy 6666.67 gallons. Therefore 6666.67*3.05=20333.34, my expected return would be 333.34.

Comment: That is right.  I don't know if your class requires you to say something like "suppose I buy $x$ gallons of oil, my expected return is $.05x$, so I should invest all the money" to demonstrate the strategy is optimal